# Notation for multiplying each element of n-tuple with scalar

Tags: notation

I've got an n-tuple $T$ of the following form: $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{++}^n$.

I'd like to multiply each element of this tuple with a constant $k=5$ (or any other real number).

Is there a neat (short) notation for this?

The only way I can think of is the following: $(kx_1, kx_2,...,kx_n) | x_i \in \mathbb{R}_{++} \land k=5 $

I'm fairly new to mathematical notations so please be patient.

Comment: If $x = (x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n)$, then commonly understood notation for scalar multiplication is $$kx = k(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n) = (kx_1, kx_2, \dotsc, kx_n).$$

Comment: Could I also write this as $k*D | D \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{++}^n$? @XanderHenderson Thanks!

Comment: You could use the notation $kD = \{ kx : x \in D\}$, where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\}$.